# How to align a rounded button inside a div using bootstarp

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div inside which I am trying to put a button, which should be responsive.

placing button inside is working fine but the issue is it is not responsive as the div changes its size accordingly.

```
<div className="mainDiv row">
     <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mb-4">
        <div className="mt-5">
            <button className="btn testclass">
                <div className="showDot">top</div>
                <div className="someText">Middle</div>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Css

```
.testclass {
border: 4px solid #727272 !important;
border-radius: 50% !important;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-color: red;
```

}

Working example

```css
.mainDiv {
  background-color: lightgreen !important;
  height: 300px
}

.testclass {
  border: 4px solid #727272 !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1 col-xl-4 mb-1 mainDiv">
    <div class="mt-5">
      <button class="btn testclass">
         <div class="showDot">top</div>
         <div class="someText">Middle</div>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What i want to do is to align that circular button at the bottom center of that container, which will be in center for every size (responsive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing much need to change. Only need to add few bootstrap classes.
I have added three class as below mention -

**d-flex**  - for flexbox

**align-items-center**  - for vertical center

**justify-content-center** - for horizontal center

```
 <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1 col-xl-4 mb-1 mainDiv 
  d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
```

also remove `mt-5` class from child div

Answer (score 1):

Working Example,

```css
.mainDiv {
  background-color: lightgreen !important;
  height: 300px
}

.testclass {
  border: 4px solid #727272 !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
}
.mt1-5{
   margin-top: 100px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1 col-xl-4 mb-1 mainDiv">
    <div class="mt1-5">
      <button class="btn testclass">
                            <div class="showDot">top</div>
                            <div class="someText">Middle</div>
                        </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Add this ,

```
.mt-5{
   margin-top: 100px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Remove margin-top: 3rem !important in .mt-5 class or make a new class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this next thing in your html.
On the parent element insert this.

```
<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1 col-xl-4 mb-1 mainDiv" style="display: table;text-align: center;">
```

and on the child element insert this.

```
   <div class="" style=" display: table-cell;vertical-align: bottom;">
```

I have tried with the snippet you provided and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two things:

**First:**

```
class="d-flex justify-content-center"
```

You should place this in the class where is the `mainDiv`.
This should move your element to the center of the page.

**Second:**

```
class="d-flex align-items-end"
```

You should place this in the class where is the `mainDiv`.
This should move your element to the bottom of the page.

Remember, `d-flex` is only needed one time in each element class.

So in the end you should write in the element called `mainDiv`

```
class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end"
```

Comment: could you help me with small snippet ? for both

Comment: It works for me, make sure you have called bootstrap-4 correctly

Comment: The element doesn't move at all or ir does crazy things?

Comment: It dosen't move, a small snippet can help

Comment: Substitute className="mainDiv row" for className="mainDiv row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end"

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to align a button to be in center of a div

If Yes,
Then, you just need to add this in `.testclass`

```
.testclass {
  border: 4px solid #727272 !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Working example:
https://codepen.io/fasid/pen/bGwKvdy

> What i want to do is to align that circular button at the bottom center of that container, which will be in center for every size (responsive)

try changing above `top: 40%` to `top: 90%`